Pourquoi ne dit on pas "ma amie" mais "mon amie" au féminin
Pourquoi ne dit on pas "ma amie" mais "mon amie" au féminin? On dit pourtant bien ma pote, ma copine, ma sœur, ma carotte... D’où vient cette exception?

C'est le cas de tous les mots féminins qui commencent par une voyelle, pour rendre la liaison plus simple à prononcer et plus agréable à l'oreille.

mon agrafe, mon étagère, mon idée, mon origine, mon utopie

Ça s'applique aussi d'autres pronoms comme ton, son etc.

Il ne s'agit pas d'une exception spécifique à amie mais bien d'une règle. Les possessifs mon, ton et son sont utilisés devant tous les mots féminins commençant par une voyelle.
Une étoile mon étoile, mon échelle, mon associée, mon histoire, mon auto, mon usine, etc.
Devant un H non muet, le hiatus est préservé et ne pose pas de problème de prononciation (comparer sa hache, sa herse et son habileté, son herbe).
On peut quand même noter qu'en ancien français, la forme m'amie existait pour "ma amie", de même "ma amour" ➔ "m'amour" ➔ "mamours".

Oui m'amour c'est pareil.

Pour l'explication historique: les déterminants possessifs féminins se comportaient jadis comme "la", on disait donc bien "m'amie". Le masculin par contre variait entre le modèle invariable en "mon" et un modèle similaire à "le". On disait donc aussi bien "mon ami" que "m'ami".
Quand la première option l'a emporté au masculin, elle a été étendue au féminin également. Puisqu'on abandonnait "m'ami" au profit de "mon ami", alors on est aussi passé de "m'amie" à "mon amie"
